# T-SQL ORDER BY one column with mixing by another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I really need your help. I have to get some data from SQL table with some specific ordering. All data should be ordered by `KeyID` by descending but if there will be some number of rows with the same data in second column, they have to be separated by another rows.

For example, we have such table:

```
KeyID    UserID
1         15
2         17
3         19
4         19
5         15
6         17
7         17
```

In result table it should be

```
KeyID    UserID
7         17
5         15
6         17
4         19
2         17
3         19
1         15
```

Is there any way to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to produce exactly the sort you are looking for, but it should spread out the keyids:

```
order by row_number() over (partition by userId order by keyid desc),
         keyid desc
```

Comment: this is not exactly what I need, but it's the best variant

Answer (score 0):

This should work for the simple case of having at most 2 consecutive records sharing the same `UserID`:

```
SELECT KeyID, UserID
FROM (
   SELECT KeyID, UserID,
          rn, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, grp ORDER BY KeyID DESC) AS rnk
   FROM (
      SELECT KeyID, UserID,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KeyID DESC) AS rn,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KeyID DESC) - 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID 
                                ORDER BY KeyID DESC) AS grp
      FROM mytable) AS t) AS x
ORDER BY rn + rnk, KeyID
```

Answer (score 0):

This below query is working fine as your expected result.

```
WITH TEMP AS(
SELECT  *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY KEYID DESC)ROW,
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY KEYID DESC)ROW1 
FROM    USERS
        )

SELECT  KEYID,USERID 
FROM    (
        SELECT KEYID,USERID,ROW1,ROW FROM TEMP
        WHERE ROW<>2
        UNION 
        SELECT KEYID,USERID,ROW1+1 ROW1, ROW FROM TEMP
        WHERE ROW=2
        )B
ORDER BY ROW1 ASC
```

Here is my output:[image]